# Is it better to have as many commits as possible in Git or as few as possible?

Tags: git

I recently had a debate with a colleague and he is adamant that having as few commits as possible is better, due to merge conflicts. I argue that the more detail you have by using as many commits as possible, the better.

Is it better to have more commits, or less, and why?

Comment: This seems to opinion based.

Comment: Surely there has to be a right and wrong one in the story?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you coworker explain *why* exactly having a lot of commits would cause problems with merge conflicts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your colleague discourages many commits because that somehow causes more merge conflicts, then that is incorrect, the number of commits alone has nothing to do with merge conflicts. If your code is going to conflict when you merge a branch into another, it won't matter if that branch has 1 commit or 1,000, it's going to cause a conflict either way.

This is because, in general, Git only compares the state of the code ***at the final commits*** on each branch, along with the "best" common ancestor between them (as determined by the merge algorithm). Any intermediary commits between the ancestor and the tip commit of a branch won't even be considered.

That said, when you share your history with other people, you might want to strike a balance between having your commits detailed enough to be useful, but also sparse enough to present a clear, easily understood history. Sometimes all your branch needs is 1 commit to clearly show a history of changes, and other times you might need more. Whether to do it one way or another is situational.

If you're just working on a branch privately, you can commit as often as you want, however you want, because you can always rewrite your history to be shorter and clearer later, before you share your changes with other people.

Comment: It's worth adding that while a regular merge is endpoint-based (so that number of commits is irrelevant), there is `git-imerge` which will do merges commit-wise, as it were.  Doing them commit-wise is logically O(n²); however, imerge attempts to linearize this, and "balanced" commits will be easier to resolve.  If everything is one giant commit, imerge is just regular merge.  If each character-change is its own commit, imerge does "too much" work.  So merge has no effect on #-of-commits, but imerge should encourage balance.

Answer (score 4):

Commit early, commit often. [Good article on this topic by Seth Robertson.](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/)

I don't understand the fear of merge conflicts argument for committing seldom. The bigger the commits the more likely you are to have merge conflicts, and the harder they are to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

Try and commit one logical block of work. Both of the following commit messages are bad practices:

**Corrected spelling in the feature X** (especially when the last commit made was related to X)

**Updated files for feature X, deleted bogus files and add some more unrelated files**

No one is stopping you from committing your work every couple minutes or once a week. But if you want a clean, readable history, it is better to commit often and squash related commits into a more meaningful one before pushing your changes.

Comment: "Corrected spelling in the feature X" seems like a unit of work to me, I don't see anything wrong with it. I agree that the 2nd one isn't very good though.

Comment: It is good if feature X is implemented some commits ago. Otherwise you can amend the thing right back in.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean, this is true.