# Git merge branch one commit at a time?

Tags: git, merge

I have a relatively big feature branch that I want to merge with master, and the merge produces quite a lot of conflicts. Is there a way to merge those branches one commit at a time so I could resolve one conflict at a time and check if everything's working?

One solution I can think of is to use rebase instead of merge, but then the history will become flat and I don't want that. I'm ok with creating additional "merge fix" commits, though, if it helps.

Comment: You might consider git-imerge. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162930/how-can-i-find-out-which-git-commits-cause-conflicts and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875061/is-it-better-to-have-as-many-commits-as-possible-in-git-or-as-few-as-possible

Comment: @torek thanks, that looks like exactly what I need

Comment: For what it's worth, I should add that I once tried to use imerge on a massive code base and it was just too slow. While burning several days on this we also tried an alternate approach and finished that much earlier. I had a third alternative in mind (manual merges at chosen points) as another strategy but never had time to try it. The alternative that did work was basically an en-masse "re-do what we did, starting from new code base", i.e., the equivalent of roughly 400 cherry-pick operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of rebasing the big feature branch, you can instead rebase a copy of that. With all the conflicts resolved after the rebase you can then pull back the difference:

```
$ git checkout -b big_feature_branch.rebased big_feature_branch
$ git rebase master big_feature_branch.rebased
# Resolve all conflicts
$ git checkout big_feature_branch
$ git diff big_feature_branch big_feature_branch.rebased | git apply -
$ git commit -am "merge fix"
$ git branch -D big_feature_branch.rebased
```

Answer (score 6):

You could merge "one commit at a time", but it would create a merge commit for each commit you have on the other branch, which is quite heavy.

To do that, just look at where you diverged from `master`, and while on the `master` branch, issue `git merge <commit_id>` for each commit starting from that.

Otherwise, just resolve the big conflicts once and for all, and everyone reading your commit history will thank you.

A good way to address this problem in the feature would be the regulary merge master in your feature branch.

Comment: Would squashing all the merge commits work, or will that break something?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend squashing merge commits, since it will make the history weird, having octopuses merges everywhere.

Comment: I think this is an ideal place to squash, as your combining the various stages of the merge into one commit.